# I forked a package, what do I need to run to get it inside my project?

Tags: php, composer-php

I forked a package and I've also completed this step inside my own project:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

basically:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

now that it's added to my composer.json what do I need to run to get this fork inside my own project?

do I need to run "composer update" or some other command, so that latest updates I made on the fork are available inside my own project.

Comment: That title sounds dirty

Comment: `composer install` or `composer update monolog/monolog`

Comment: thanks Dan08, much obliged